# Magento-2 : Add "Use Config Settings" check-box to custom block form

Tags: magento2, adminform

I have custom admin form and want to show "**Use Config Settings"** check-box to just under form field.

**For Example**, [image]
In product edit page, If you open "Advanced Inventory" link, you will see "Use Config Settings" which is display default system configuration value.

I want to do same thing in my custom admin form.

Any one had did this? Please share your solution here.

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution for this if so can you please post here.